# Disable jQuery function on click element

Tags: jquery, function, disable

I am using this function to autorotate between tabs on my website:

```
$(function(autorotate) {
  var lis = $("#aanpak .tab_titles .tab"),
   currentHighlight = 0;
   N = 5;//interval in seconds
    setInterval(function() {
      currentHighlight = (currentHighlight + 1) % lis.length;
 lis.removeClass('active_tab').eq(currentHighlight).addClass('active_tab');
  }, N * 1000);
});
```

Working fine. But I want this function to be disabled if I click on `#aanpak .tab_titles .tab`. Can someone help with this. So basically it is all about disabling this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a var, let say `myInterval`, and then assign the `setInterval` to it, to be able to use `clearInterval` to stop it when `#aanpak .tab_titles .tab` is clicked:

```
var myInterval;
$(function(autorotate) {
   var lis = $("#aanpak .tab_titles .tab"),
   currentHighlight = 0;
   N = 5; //interval in seconds
   myInterval = setInterval(function() {
      currentHighlight = (currentHighlight + 1) % lis.length;
      lis.removeClass('active_tab').eq(currentHighlight).addClass('active_tab');
   }, N * 1000);
});
$("#aanpak .tab_titles .tab").on('click', function(){
    clearInterval(myInterval);
});
```